# Unexpected Termination error SSIS PAckage

Tags: ssis

I have a recently developed SSIS package which exports data from SQL  server to an excel file. This package runs fine in lower environment but fails in Prod with Unexpected Termination Error message when called on by the job.  It ran fine one time in prod. After that I changed the export folder location(SSIS parameter). The folder location is stored  in one of the configuration table but I didn't change anything in the package itself as the folder parameter is called at run time from the table. When I run the package manually in prod, it runs without any issue.

Any idea why I am getting Unexpected Termination error? Is it because I changed the parameter value in the configuration table but didn't change anything on the package itself? Is there any way to get the detail error message?

Thanks in advance

I ran the package in prod manually but it failed with Unexpected Termination error when called by a job

Comment: Change the value back to the original folder and if it works, then you have identified this change caused the package to fail. There might be detailed error information but whether that's in the SSISDB and accessible via native reports is unknown based on your question as it stands. If SSISDB, then using SSMS, navigate to the SSIS node and expand it and find execution reports for said package. If it's not SSISDB, then ensure the call to DTEXEC has `/rep EIW` or better and that will report errors, information and warning events. Either way, update your question with the info and we can help

Comment: I did similar change regarding the folder in lower environment but I am not getting that error. It works fine. As this issue is only in Prod, its little tricky to debug. I have similar SSIS package which fails every time on the first run but it succeeds on the second run. I don't see any other error in the catalog.

Comment: Did you change the export folder to something that has different access permission from the first folder? Check to make sure the service account used by SQL Agent has write access to the new folder in Prod.

Comment: Don't have the solution yet. But it looks like this issue may be because of trying to export large volume of data to Excel( 300000 rows). Permissions are all good.